Understanding a German pun
In Joshua Blau's Phonology and Morphology of Biblical Hebrew (p189), he writes:

The heyday of the theory that the first two radicals
constitute the biradical base was in the second half of the nineteenth century
when, e.g., F. Mühlau and W. Volck, in their editions of Gesenius’s lexicon to
the Old Testament (beginning with the 8th edition, 1878) have, according to
Bergsträsser’s pun (1918–29: 2. 3) “diese Anschaung . . . durch und damit ad
absurdum geführt” (in a somewhat pedantic English translation, spoiling the
pun, ‘by overdoing the use of this method, they showed its absurdity’).

Although I believe I understand the German, I don't see what the pun is supposed to be. Can anyone assist?
(In case the context is relevant, he's discussing a theory of how to understand the basic meaning of Hebrew word roots by breaking the three-letter roots down to a two-letter (ostensibly) more basic sub-.)

The Bergsträßer quote seems to be from Hebräische Grammatik. Mit Benutzung der von E. Kautzsch bearbeiteten 28. Auflage von Wilhelm Gesenius’ hebräischer Grammatik, verfasst von G. Bergsträßer, Vogel, Leipzig 1918. I suspect "2. 3" refers to volume 2, §3. Unfortunately, I can only locate a digitalisation of volume 1.

@ccprog It would seem from Blau's writing that you wouldn't need more than the quoted piece to get the pun, but maybe I'm mistaken.

I can see a pun (well, what a philologist educated in the 19th century would consider a pun) in the shortened sentence, but can also imagine that the missing part changes the possible references of "durch und damit". I'd have prefered to see the original.

@ccprog Gotcha. I'll see if I can track the full thing down.

@ccprog Starts on the third line of the lower small-text paragraph of page 3 here.

Seems I am geoblocked from veiwing the book. I only get a "contents unavailable".

@ccprog See here.

Thx. This confirms tohuwabohu's explanation. Even more, if you look closely, it says "durch- und damit ad absurdum geführt". The hyphen after "durch-" (omited in your above quote) links it clearly to "geführt".

IMHO you don't need to use "overdo" if I understand the pun right - a simple "apply" fits better. Something like:

By mere application, they showed the absurditiy of that method.

If this is right, the pun consists of using the verb "führen" in two (different) senses - first, as part of the separable verb "durchführen" - "sie führten durch" and second, as part of the phrase "ad absurdum führen". This combines "durchführen" and "ad absurdum führen" grammatically and semantically.

It should be added that "die Anschaung durchführen" (literally: execute an assumption) is not a meaningfull expression, making the pun quite akward. – Also, the construction "durch und damit"  reminds of the common expression "durch und durch", which just like the English "through and through" means most rigorously.

The pun is slightly hidden: first there is the (gramatical, elliptical) shortening of "durchführen" as in "to exercise/to execute" and "ad absurdum führen", omitting the first "führen". This is well-phrased juggling of the German language by an educated writer who knows how to condense meaning to prose. Second there is the description of the scholars who were also studied experts in their field, and used that knowledge and wisdom to reduce that "Anschauung" (point of view) to some absurdity. So we face the ridicule of the people who started to get a full grasp of the object of their studies to figure out (eventually) that this thing does not exist or vanishes at close inspection, plus the strong "führen" (to lead, to direct, like in "Der Führer" for Hitler) that indicates their determinism/ strong will to get things done. So the ellipsis in the narrative runs parallel to the result that was a sort of void, Shakespears's much adoe about nothing.
